# How to insert letter into appended data?

Tags: python

I just want to insert an 'R' prior to every 'raceNumber'.

My code:

```
import requests
import json
tabevents = []
request3 = requests.get('https://api.beta.tab.com.au/v1/tab-info-service/racing/dates/2020-07-27/meetings?jurisdiction=NSW&returnOffers=true&returnPromo=false')
json3 = request3.json()
for m in json3['meetings']:
    for r in m['races']:
        tabevents.append((m['meetingName'],r[{R}'raceNumber']))
print(tabevents)
```

Output of code:

```
('CESSNOCK', 1), ('CESSNOCK', 2), ('CESSNOCK', 3)
```

Desired output of code:

```
('CESSNOCK', 'R1'), ('CESSNOCK', 'R2'), ('CESSNOCK', 'R3')
```

Comment: `tabevents.append((m['meetingName'],f"R{r['raceNumber']}"))`

Comment: Desired output is not valid python

Answer (score 1):

If you have to append a string (R) to an Integer you will also have to convert (1,2,3) to string

```
tabevents.append((m['meetingName'], 'R' + str(r['raceNumber'])))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension altogether:

```
import requests

request3 = requests.get(
    'https://api.beta.tab.com.au/v1/tab-info-service/racing/dates/2020-07-27/meetings?jurisdiction=NSW&returnOffers=true&returnPromo=false')
json3 = request3.json()
tabevents = [(m['meetingName'], f"R{r['raceNumber']}") for m in json3['meetings'] for r in m['races']]
print(tabevents)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close and on the right track. Just fix this line:

```py
 tabevents.append((m['meetingName'], 'R%d' % r['raceNumber']))
```

If you're running Python3, alernatively you could use f-strings:

```py
 tabevents.append((m['meetingName'], f"R{r['raceNumber']}"))
```